# SP Online permission for user to define his personal default view

Tags: sharepoint-online, view, default

I have a request from users to be able to define the custom view they created (through the "Save view as" button) as default.
With my permission level, I well have this option to select the default view (for all). But is there a way to allow each contributor to define the default view he will see?
I have dived in the permission levels and list advanced setting, but didn't find anything about this.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid that we could not achieve this.
Some view settings can achieve the same view, different people show different items,you could have a try.